# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngOriginalError' of undefined for HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to add a spinner within the span of HttpRequest and HttpResponse. After adding a service named HttpServiceInterceptor in providers list of app.module.ts, throwing ngOriginalError.

Comment: Are you sure that this error is related to that `HttpInterceptor` service which  you are implementing ?

Comment: could you reproduce this issue on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: how did you solve this issue?

Comment: No, It was not solved and we ended up not using the HttpInterceptor